# Get desired capabilities with Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, appium, python-appium

I don't know how to get desired capabilities I've set with Appium Python client.

What I need specifically to know is which platform is set, is it iOS or Android?

I have Appium driver like this.

```
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(config['server_url'], config['device_config'])

server_url = http://localhost:4723/wd/hub

device_config = samsung_galaxy_nexus_6_0

'samsung_galaxy_nexus_6_0': {
        'app': '/Users/majdukovic/Documents/no_root_ux.apk',
        'platformName': 'Android',
        'platformVersion': '6.0',
        'deviceName': 'Galaxy Nexus 6.0',
        'avd': 'Galaxy_Nexus_6.0',
```

I need something like this 
`self.driver.get_capabilities('platformName')`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Already set capabilities can be accessed with `self.driver.desired_capabilities['capabilty_name_here']`

for example:

`self.driver.desired_capabilities['platformName']`
`self.driver.desired_capabilities['deviceName']`

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Android environment or iOS environment

```
# Android environment
import unittest
from appium import webdriver

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.2'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Android Emulator'
desired_caps['app'] = PATH('../../../apps/selendroid-test-app.apk')

self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)



# iOS environment
import unittest
from appium import webdriver

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '7.1'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone Simulator'
desired_caps['app'] = PATH('../../apps/UICatalog.app.zip')

self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

**Source:** https://github.com/appium/python-client

*If it doesn't help what you need then simply comment below.*

Comment: thanks Meghshyam, but this is for setting capabilities, I know how to set them, I just need method which returns capabilities. Something like `self.driver.get_capabilities('platformName')` so with that I would get either 'iOS' or 'Android'.

Comment: Newby mistake, I was using () instead of [], platform version and other cpas can be accessed with `self.driver.desired_capabilities['platformName']`